# How do I change a Java ME device System time?

Tags: java-me, nokia, motorola, sony

I'm developing an application that needs to synchronize the time on a server with the time on the device.
Blackberry devices have the net.rim.device.api.system.Device.setDateTime(long dateTimeMillis) method for this. I'm looking for something similar in Java ME devices.

I can live with manufacturer specific APIs - specialy nokia, sony ericsson and motorola ones, and most JSRs.

Does anyone know if there is any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Most manufacturers, such as Nokia, don't have that functionality in Java. You may need to take a look into Symbian C++ and other platform specific development tools.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do with Java-me for some security reasons. So you can't change the internal time of system. You can possible to get the current time only.